# Selenium AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute send_keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use Selenium for automate a login in the website https://clientes.ecuabots.com/user/login

This is my code:

```
class EcuabotsTest(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/mnt/c/Users/Barbara/Documents/Formación Continua/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get('https://clientes.ecuabots.com/user/login')
    driver.maximize_window()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(15)

def test_search_email_input(self):
    email_field = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="input-15"]')
    email_field.clear()
    
    email_field.send_keys('email@email.com)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

but when i try this way i have the error: AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute send_keys

- I tried to use email_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input-15"]') (singular) but i get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: No such element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="input-15"]"
- I tried the find email input with id, CSS selector and full XPath but it isn't work
- I tried to use email_field[0].send_keys('email@email.com) but i get the first error again

Thank you very much beforehand for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to wait until the page is loaded and the element is presented there
2. You should use `find_element_by_xpath`, not `find_elements_by_xpath`
3. Your locator is wrong

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

email_input_css = 'input[placeholder="Email Address"]'

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

email = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, email_input_css)))
email_field.clear()
email_field.send_keys('email@email.com)
```

Comment: You can use any element attributes values.